# Provider error hardhat

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

When i want to deploy my contract with this command:

> npx hardhat run --network goerli scripts/deploy.js

I get this error:

> ProviderError: HttpProviderError
> at HttpProvider.request (/Users/alirezamac/Documents/Token-dex/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)

And here is my config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require ("dotenv").config()

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.INFURA_GOERLI_ENDPOINT,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 5
    },
  },
};
```

and also this is my deploy file:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
 const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken")
 const token = await Token.deploy();
 await token.deployed()
console.log("Congratulations!! Your token deployed, Here's token address:", token.address);

 const Dex = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Dex2")
 const myDex = await Dex.deploy(token.address)
 await token.deployed()

 console.log("Here's your dex contract address:", myDex.address);

}
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Comment: seems like it's an issue with your infura url make sure that is correct first, and then my second idea would be that it is not reading the url from the .env file correctly. To test that change the url to your actual url and if it works then there is an issue with your .env setup are you using vanilla js or a framework like react?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some lines to `node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/providers/http.js` to debug. After every `isErrorResponse` check add: `console.log(response)` or `console.log(jsonRpcResponse)`.

Most likely it's an error inside your contracts or deploy script (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Thre is a typo in await `token.deployed()`
should be `myDex.deployed()`

That could be the reason the provider is reverting without any reason

Answer (score 0):

Solved this error by looking the ganache's console and seeing that the tx was reverted due to an error caused by incorrect assignment of an account to a role.